# How to fix error setting key event on form by its ID?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I want to add google map into my Laravel 8 /  tailwindcss 2 / Alpinejs 2.8 app
and I found example
https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-find-addresses-with-coordinates-via-google-maps-api/

As I do not use jquery, but alpinejs I got an error :

```
alpine.js:115 Alpine Error: "TypeError: form_ad_location_edit.on is not a function"
```

When I try to remake code :

$('form').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
if (keyCode === 13) {
e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
});

into :

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.ads.ad_locations.'. ( $isInsert ? 'store' : 'update'), [1, ( $adLocation->id ?? '' ), 1 ] ) }}" method="POST" id="form_ad_location_edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">

let form_ad_location_edit = document.querySelector("#form_ad_location_edit")
console.log('form_ad_location_edit::')
console.log(form_ad_location_edit)

form_ad_location_edit.on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

In the console I see that I got valid form elememt ?

Which way is valid ?

Thanks!

Comment: `HTMLElement` does not have an `on` method.

Comment: Does it mean that I* got value to form_ad_location_edit in wrong way? Which way is correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found decision with addEventListener method :

```
let form_ad_location_edit = document.querySelector("#form_ad_location_edit")
adLocationLng= parseFloat(adLocationLng)
adLocationLat= parseFloat(adLocationLat)
form_ad_location_edit.addEventListener("keyup keypress", function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

That works for me.